# How can I declare a method which returns an Option value in Thrift/Scrooge?

Tags: scala, thrift, future, scrooge

I'm using Scrooge to generate Thrift interface code as follows:

```
struct UserInfo {
  1: i64 userId,
  2: string name
}

service userservice {
  UserInfo getUserById(1:i64 userId)
}
```

Scrooge will generate this method from the IDL file above: `def getUserById(userId: Long): Future[UserInfo]`.

However, in scala, a value which might be absent could be represent via the Option data-type. Therefore, the thrift code generated in Scala-way might looks like `def getUserById(userId: Long): Future[Option[UserInfo]]`. While the Option is scala-specific, is there anyway to make Scrooge support this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `list<T>` to imitate option. And since Option can be treated as a collection of 0|1 element this replacement also correct from semantic perspective.

For converting this list to option in your Scala code you can use `headOption` method.